# Как в Thymeleaf вписать в th:utext html-тэг с классом?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Такая проблема:
Когда я пытаюсь реализовать данный код, то у меня все внутри подчеркивается красным и я не знаю как исправить это:

```html
main.instagram.subscribe=Подпишись на нас в Instagram

<h1 class="text-header-3" th:utext="#{main.instagram.subscribe} + '<a href="#" class="text-color-orange">@example</a>'">
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на данный вопрос я нашел в [данном ресурсе](https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/thymeleaf-html-element-replacement/). Там представлено два решения, но я предпочитаю лишь один из них.

Мы пишем следующиее:

```html
<h1 class="text-header-3">
    <span th:remove="tag" th:text="#{main.instagram.subscribe}"></span>
    <a href="#" class="text-color-orange" style="text-decoration: none">@example</a>
</h1>
```

Данный код будет конвертироваться в:

```html
<h1 class="text-header-3">
    Подпишись на нас в Instagram 
    <a href="#" class="text-color-orange" style="text-decoration: none">@example</a>
</h1>
```

Идея проста:
Текст из переменной пишем в спомогательный тэг `<span>`, с помощью `th:remove="tag"` убираем тэг `span` и все.